# Ubuntu 12.04 Server on VMWare - apt-get failing to hit repos

Tags: ubuntu, apt, vmware-player, aptitude

So, I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit server instance running on VMWare player. Everything appears fine at the surface. Even internet connectivity appears good as I can perform both pings out to google & us.archive.ubuntu.com and nslookups against the same locations and both work fine. Yet, when I try to run apt-get update, it barks that it cannot connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com.

I'm getting a tad frazzled now as I have tried both nat and bridged. With Nat, pings and nslookups fail. With bridged they work.

What else could I be missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, nevermind. Even though my firewall indicated that VMWare was not blocked, it would seem that there was a setting to "allow supported VMs access". Once I enabled this, all was well in okie-dokie land.

Deuces